# Error with python-setuptools doing "sudo easy_install python-graph-core"

Tags: ubuntu, python, easy-install

Using easy_install, part of the python-setuptools, I get the following error:

```
$ sudo easy_install python-graph-core
[sudo] password for dan: 
Searching for python-graph-core
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/python-graph-core/
Reading http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/
Reading http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/downloads/list?can=1
Reading http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/downloads/list
Best match: python-graph-core 1.7.0
Downloading http://python-graph.googlecode.com/files/python-graph-core-1.7.0.tar.gz
Processing python-graph-core-1.7.0.tar.gz
Running python-graph-core-1.7.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-GwpYiM/python-graph-core-1.7.0/egg-dist-tmp-1yqbyV
setup.py:8: Warning: 'as' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==0.6c9', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1671, in main
    with_ei_usage(lambda:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1659, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1675, in <lambda>
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/distutils/dist.py", line 994, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 211, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 446, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 476, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 655, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 930, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 919, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 27, in run_setup
    lambda: execfile(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 63, in run
    return func()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 29, in <lambda>
    {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
  File "setup.py", line 8
    except ImportError as ie:
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any suggestions to what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: just for info: ubuntu package page (karmic): http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/python-setuptools .. ubuntu package buglist: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-setuptools/+bugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not an issue with easy-install.  This error is from having python 2.5 instead of python 2.6 which is required by python-graph.

Comment: since the *python-setuptools* package includes */usr/bin/easy-install-2.6* i presume you can install the ubuntu python2.6 packages to get this functionality.  (a *dpkg-reconfigure* or *update-alternatives* may be necessary tho.)